# Как отключить в браузере Chrome появление диалогового окна "Сохранить пароль для этого сайта в сервисе "Google Chrome"" используя Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Использую Selenium chromedriver. После авторизации на тестируемой страничке появляется диалоговое сообщение типа: [image: Сохранить пароль для этого сайта в сервисе "Google Chrome"?]

Мне данное диалоговое окно мешает. Можно ли как то отключить его появление используя непосредственно selenium и chromedriver. Что то типа:

```
self.profile = ChromeOptions()
self.profile.addArguments("аргумент который отключает появление такого окна")
```

Вариант с отключением через настройки Chrome не предлагайте !!!

Answer (score 2):

```
self.profile = ChromeOptions()
self.profile.addArguments("--disable-save-password-bubble")
```

Comment: Не работает данный код, все равно появляется диалоговое окно, которое просит сохранить пароль. Скажите откуда вы взяли данную информацию?

Comment: Вот ссылка на то, что это не работает https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1015

Answer (score 0):

Найди элемент закрытия этого всплывающего окна, а далее element.Click(); Тогда его будет закрывать непосредственно Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.profile.addArguments("--no-sandbox")
```